# Embedded entity not loaded

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I am trying to store the entity `Job` with an embedded entity `Range` in the Google App Engine data store (local test system). When I persist a new entity, I can see that the properties of the embedded entity are persisted. However, if I load the entity by Id or query, the range property is null.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Job {

    // embedded entity
    @PersistenceCapable
    @EmbeddedOnly
    public static class Range {

        @Persistent
        private long start;

        @Persistent
        private long length;

        public long getLength() {
            return this.length;
        }

        public void setStart(long start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        public long getStart() {
            return start;
        }
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    @Embedded
    private Range range;

    // getters and setters ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again, the answer is: It's not a bug, it's a feature. It turns out the embedded entity was loaded lazily and as long as I did not call the getter, the properties were not populated